# how to add disqus to a page with multiple posts and infinite scroll

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, disqus

In my application, I have multiple posts and they are loaded one at a time. Now I need to add disqus commenting widget with each post. Please note that this application is made with angularjs. I have already gone through: http://www.devinterface.com/blog/en/2012/01/how-to-insert-more-disqus-box-in-single-page/

However this approach requires me to load the js file multiple times which is an overhead and I want to avoid doing this. Posts are loaded with ajax request.

I have also used this plugin from angularjs: https://github.com/kirstein/angular-disqus but this did not address to my issue either. I guess it does not support multiple disqus widgets on the same page.

Comment: for infinite scroll you can use this script working with jquery https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll this working with ajax so maybe will be helpful.